# JavaScript push method pushing to all arrays instead of one in Vue3 ref array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs3

I have a Vue ref object that I declare and then make an empty array of arrays:

```
const modifiedSchedules = ref([])

onMounted(() => {
     modifiedSchedules.value = Array(selectedUserIDs.value.length).fill([]);
})
```

Then, I try to push to one of the sub-arrays like this:

```
const myFund = (index: number, myObject: {})... => {
    modifiedSchedules.value[index].push(myObject);
}
```

What I'm finding is that this code pushes to ALL the arrays in *modifiedSchedules* instead of just the one at the index. Am I misunderstanding something about how this works?

Comment: those are references to the same array when you initializing using fill

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121982/strange-behavior-of-an-array-filled-by-array-prototype-fill